# Fetch data from Database and show in TextBox

Tags: c#, asp.net

[image]I have a table from where I want to fetch data and show in the `TextBox` the data are `StudentFirstName` and `SchoolID` along with them I need two empty `TextBoxes` next to them am not sure how to do that.

My data base table

```
StudentFirstName    SchoolID      StudCourse
abc                  sc123         Bcom
cef                  sc155         Bcom
gij                  sc133         Bcom
abc                  sc122         BCA
cef                  sc156         BCA
gij                  sc144         BCA
```

C#

```
using (MySqlConnection myConnection = new MySqlConnection(constr))
{
     string oString = "Select * from euser_student WHERE  StudCourse=@StudCourse order by StudentFirstName  ASC";
     MySqlCommand oCmd = new MySqlCommand(oString, myConnection);

     oCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@StudCourse", StudCourse);   
     myConnection.Open();
     using (MySqlDataReader oReader = oCmd.ExecuteReader())
     {
          if (oReader == null || !oReader.HasRows)
          {
               ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page), "alert", "alert('No Student Found')", true);
          }
          else
          {
              while (oReader.Read())
              { 

              }
          }
          myConnection.Close();
     }               
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`SqlDataReader.GetString Method`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.getstring(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the value of the specified column as a string Like this:

```
while (oReader.Read())
{
    TextBox1.Text = oReader.GetString(1); // 1 is the Parameter that is The zero-based column ordinal you can change it to what you want
    TextBox2.Text = oReader.GetString(2);
}
```

Check this to learn more : [`Retrieving Data Using a DataReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/haa3afyz(v=vs.110).aspx).

But If you want to show more than one row it would be better if you use a `GridView` control to show data. First add a `GridView` to your `aspx` like this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"></asp:GridView>
```

And then:

```
GridView1.DataSource = oReader;
GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: that is working fine am sorry it is my mistake wat i want is i say if i have 3 users against `StudCourse` `Bcom` i need all three names to be shown in the text box and in case if there are 5 i want 5 names to be shown in my terms as per my knowledge i want a dynamically created text boxs

Comment: @Shaik...So why you don't use a `GridView` for this purpose?

Comment: Am not sure how to use it and I have a quick question is it possible to add empty text boxs next to each fetch

Comment: If u can help me I would be thank full to u and i to want to save then back after all the empty text box are filled

Comment: @Shaik...Define a `GridView` and then just `GridView1.DataSource = oReader;
 GridView1.DataBind();`. Read more here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Ok vl thaks for your support in my case if u would have suggested an example i would have been thank full to u